# "service networking stop" failed to stop on Ubuntu loaded as VM on Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 64 bit on top of Oracle VM installed on Windows 7 Operating System.

This is the error message I am getting

```
  stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method-call", sender=":1.10" (uid=1000) pid=1084 comm="stop networking"; interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.job" member="Stop" "error_name"="unset" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid= 0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")


  start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method-call", sender=":1.11" (uid=1000) pid=1085 comm="stop networking"; interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.job" member="Stop" "error_name"="unset" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid= 0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

Is this because of any settings I misconfigured?

What exactly it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to restart the networking service to get the eth1 interface working.

Instead of doing netwrking service restart it I just ran following command at the commandline.

```
      $sudo ifup -v eth1
```

And the interface started showing up

Though this is not a solution but it worked for me. Still I dont know what was wrong above.